# Showing associativity of gcd using a floor sum

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, ceiling-and-floor-functions, associativity

one can express the gcd of two natural numbers using Pick´s theorem via

$$ gcd(a,b) = a - b - ab + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{a} \lfloor \frac{b}{a} k \rfloor $$

I wonder how to proof the associativity. It becomes a mess.

$$ gcd(gcd(a,b),c) = gcd(a,b) - c - gcd(a,b)c + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{c} \lfloor \frac{gcd(a,b)}{c} k \rfloor $$

$$ gcd(gcd(a,b),c) = [a - b - ab + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{a} \lfloor \frac{b}{a} k \rfloor] - c - [a - b - ab + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{a} \lfloor \frac{b}{a} k \rfloor]c + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{c} \lfloor \frac{a - b - ab + 2 \sum_{j=1}^{a} \lfloor \frac{b}{a} j \rfloor}{c} k \rfloor $$

(some magic happens)

$$ gcd(gcd(a,b),c) = a - gcd(b,c) - a gcd(b,c) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{gcd(b,c)} \lfloor \frac{a}{gcd(b,c)} k \rfloor $$

$$ gcd(gcd(a,b),c) = gcd(a,gcd(b,c)) $$

Can someone help me out?

What might help are following relations:

$$ a + \sum_{k=1}^{a} \lfloor \frac{b}{a} k \rfloor = b + \sum_{k=1}^{b} \lfloor \frac{a}{b} k \rfloor $$

For natural t:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{ta} \lfloor \frac{b}{a} k \rfloor = t \sum_{k=1}^{a} \lfloor \frac{b}{a} k \rfloor + \frac{abt}{2} (t-1) $$

Comment: Do you have to use the expression for the GCD in terms of the floor function? It seems much easier to just argue directly

Comment: It is just for fun.